# HTML / CSS: Не работает :hover на другой элемент. В чем ошибка?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

столкнулся с такой проблемой при обучении по видео уроку:

Есть фотография на неё наложен полупрозрачный элемент, создающийся с помощью соседнего элемента с `opacity: 0.5`. При наведении на фотографию курсора, этот полупрозрачный элемент должен изчезать.

Если настраиваю hover и эффект от него на один и тот же элемент - то всё работает(при наведении на картинку, она изчезает). Но при попытке сделать hover на одном элементе, который влияет на другой - ничего не происходит.

Заранее спасибо!

```css
body {
  position: relative;
  color: #22222b;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

.wrapper {
  max-width: 1170px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.myPortfolio-image {
  position: relative;
}

.myPortfolio-item {
  background-color: #EDEDEE;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0.5;
  width: 313px;
  height: 404px;
  left: 26px;
  top: 33px;
}

.myPortfolio_text {
  height: 113px;
  flex-direction: column;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  text-align: center;
  color: #22222b;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 24px;
  margin-top: 17px;
  margin-left: 1px;
}

.myPortfolio_text a {
  height: 22px;
  width: 22px;
  margin-left: calc(50% - 11px);
  margin-bottom: -16px;
}

.img-hover:hover .myPortfolio-item {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<section class="myPortfolio">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="myPortfolio-container">

      <div class="myPortfolio-box">
        <div class="myPortfolio-image">
          <div class="myPortfolio-item">
            <div class="myPortfolio_text">
              <a href=""><img src="image/plus.png" alt="plus"></a>
              <p class="p1">The Day City</p>
              <p class="p2">Photo</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <img class="img-hover" src="image/townStraight.png" alt="City">
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

P. S. так тоже не работает:

```css
.img-hover:hover + .myPortfolio-item {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: Ошибка в ожиданиях: что комбинатор непосредственно **следующего** элемента (`+`) применится к **предшествующему** элементу. Но этого не должно происходить, и поэтому это не происходит  Можно попробовать использовать свойство `order` расположив оба элемента в флексбоксе, чтобы поменять их местами (только я не помню, сработает ли такой хак... попробуй).

Comment: То что я написал выше, относится к постскриптуму. А относительно примера - селектор с комбинатором **дочернего** элемента (пробел) естественно тоже не может выбирать предшествующий элемент. Комбинатора который это делает, в CSS вообще не существует пока что... так что либо менять верстку, либо пробовать хак с `order` о котором я написал выше, либо добавлять-убирать класс скрытия элемента средствами JS (по событиям `mouseenter` и `mouseleave`).

Comment: А, так элемент который надо скрыть - позиционирован абсолютно... тогда все еще проще: в разметке перемести тег изображения в позицию **до** этого элемента (то есть: `<img class="img-hover" ...><div class="myPortfolio-item">...</div>`), и тогда стиль будет применяться по селектору с комбинатором след. элемента `.img-hover:hover + .myPortfolio-item` :)

Comment: @yar85, спасибо за помощь, я добавил :hover к классу .myPortfolio-image, который является родительским для того, который я хотел убрать. Теперь буду знать, как это работает)

Comment: @yar85 сработает, если каждому элементу указать `order`

Answer (score 0):

После каждого элемента нужно писать `:hover`.

То есть, тут:

```
.img-hover:hover .myPortfolio-item {
  display: none;
}
```

После `.myPortfolio-item` не стоит `:hover`. Должно быть так:

```
.img-hover:hover .myPortfolio-item:hover {
  display: none;
}
```